# How to get other columns with are not in GROUP BY clause in a oracle select sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table MOVIE containing this data.

```
MOVIE_ID  MOVIE_TITLE              CATEGORY        SALES_AMT
--------- ------------------------ --------------- ----------
M_0000004 The Boss Baby            Animation       2000
M_0000006 Star Wars: The Last Jedi Science Fiction 3000
M_0000007 Get Out                  Horror          4000
M_0000008 Million Dollar Arm       Action          2000
M_0000009 The Conjuring            Horror          1000
M_0000012 The Dark Knight          Action          3000
```

I need the Top movies data based on `SALES_AMT` with respect to `CATEGORY`

The required result is this:

```
MOVIE_ID  MOVIE_TITLE              CATEGORY        SALES_AMT
--------- ------------------------ --------------- ----------
M_0000004 The Boss Baby            Animation       2000
M_0000006 Star Wars: The Last Jedi Science Fiction 3000
M_0000007 Get Out                  Horror          4000
M_0000012 The Dark Knight          Action          3000
```

If I use GROUP_BY option, I cannot select `MOVIE_ID` and `MOVIE_TITLE`

```
select CATEGORY, MAX(SALES_AMT)
from MOVIE
group by CATEGORY
;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with analytic functions and subquery

```
select movie_id, movie_title, category, sales_amt 
from (
  select movie_id, movie_title, category, sales_amt, 
  row_number() over (partition by category order by sales_amt desc) r 
  from movie
) where r = 1
```

Comment: you are missing an ORDER clause in your PARTITION BY to get the highest sales on top. And even with that I am not sure that it will be what he wants because if there are equality between top sales for the same category it will get only one randomly

Comment: @ThomasG Thanks I've got an error when posting answer and it eaten part of query.

Comment: @Kacper You also need a from clause in the inner query

Comment: This has been eaten as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use RANK() to achieve this:

```
SELECT
    MOVIE_ID
    , MOVIE_TITLE
    , CATEGORY
    , SALES_AMT
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MOVIE_ID
            , MOVIE_TITLE
            , CATEGORY
            , SALES_AMT
            , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CATEGORY ORDER BY SALES_AMT DESC) RNK
        FROM MOVIE
    ) Q
WHERE RNK = 1
```

This would be if you wanted to see duplicates in your results (where sales amounts were equal), otherwise, replace `RANK` with `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you run this first:

```
SQL> select deptno, min(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno;
```

and then want to get the employee who *has* that minimum salary.  Then this of course fails:

```
SQL> select deptno, empno, min(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno;

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

But you can use the KEEP syntax with a window function to assist

```
SQL> select deptno, min(sal), min(empno) 
  2    KEEP ( dense_rank FIRST order by sal) empno
  3  from emp
  4  group by deptno
  5  /

    DEPTNO   MIN(SAL)      EMPNO
---------- ---------- ----------
        10       1300       7934
        20        800       7369
        30        950       7900
```

where this is read as "EMPNO 7934 is the person who has the salary of 1300"